# Is there a reason for omitting "it" in: "As is usually seen"?

Tags: grammaticality

> As is usually seen in such mass tragedies

Why can't I say "As **it** is usually seen"

Comment: You can say so.

Comment: This appears to be an introductory clause. Which form you use might depend on the rest of the sentence. Please suggest a complete sentence so that we can see how "it" might fit into it or not.

Comment: Would you argue for _This person hasn't given sufficient context, as it is often the case_? With a slight change in emphasis, 'as is ...' can usually be replaced with 'which is ...'. The 'it' is obviously incorrect in such cases.